# Bootstrap dropdown toggle maintains hover effect after second click (toggle off)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

See an example of what I'm working on at a **[CodePen](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/Bknlh)** or **[BootPly](http://www.bootply.com/64937)**.

The issue that I am coming across is when "Publisher" is clicked, then clicked again, the hover effect stays on when the mouse is moved off to select another item.

My question is: what causes this, and how can I go about just having the hover effect *only* active when hovering, and not staying active after a toggle on & off then hover on another item?

Please kindly redirect me to another Q/A if this has been solved before.

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="display:block;position:static;margin-bottom:5px;">
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dPublisher" data-toggle="dropdown" 
              role="button" data-target="#" href="publisher.php">PUBLISHER<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledbyid="dPublisher">
        <li><a href="eeditions.php">E-Editions</a></li>
    <li><a href="digitalarchive.php">Digital Archive</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="blog.php">BLOG</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it's an iframe issue, the page doesn't see click/activity on another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style is set both on `:focus` and `:hover` in Bootstrap.  You can change it your self by either editing the Bootstrap source, or overriding it with a more specific selector.

```css
#dPublisher:focus:not(:hover) {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

[**demo**](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/vlFka)

This reads as "when `#dPublisher` is **focused** but not **hovered**, change the background and text color".

[Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot) is Chrome, Firefox, IE9, Opera 9.5, and Safari 3.2.  On unsupported browsers, it'll remain how it is currently.

---

If you want it to only disable the focus style when the dropdown is closed, we can make it a little more specific.

```css
.dropdown:not(.open) > #dPublisher:focus:not(:hover) {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

[**demo**](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/aFnbs)

Comment: i don't think that's the issue, but i can't test your solution without a 2nd dropdown in the demo to recreate the problem described by OP...

Comment: Open the CodePen in the question, and the second CodePen in my answer (I updated them).  On each, click PUBLISHER twice.  Then hover over PUBLISHER 2.  Do you see how in the first one it has the active styles even after its closed?  That's what I assumed the problem was.  I'm still getting an orange halo, though.  That is a style on the focused one.

Comment: ahh, i see what you're getting at. i thought it just to be the fact that the drop-down doesn't close when you fire  up another drop-down. this happens to me on sn iframe-based app a lot, and i share OP's pain, if that's the issue. I ended up having to postMessage() up to top to hide all it's drop-downs from the iframe's menu.